# How to create EditText hint as Text with image in android

Tags: android, image, hint

How to create EditText hint/placeholder with Text & image in android. I write like this

```
<EditText  
    android:id="@+id/name" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:lines="1"
     ................................
...............................

android:drwableLeft="@drawable/image1"
android:hint="enter name here"/>
```

Here we can see image & text (hint) within edittext but image still visible even after user enters something in that field. My requirement is if there is no text in EditText show hint with image, if  EditText is not empty hide hint text and image

Comment: how can i put some gap between hint and drawable left

Comment: You can use like this android:drawablePadding="10dp" property.

Comment: [ImageSpan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33563267/3291140) should do the trick.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you can do is set an `drawableLeft` as you did in your xml and add an `addTextChangedListener` to your EditText. When typing occurs this listener will be warned and you can check in the listener if the textsize is bigger than 0. If so, then just set the `drawableLeft` assigned in the xml programmatically to `null`.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(s.toString().length() > 0) {
        editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        //Assign your image again to the view, otherwise it will always be gone even if the text is 0 again.
        editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.image, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by placing my EditText inside a FrameLayout, and then also including a TextView inside the FrameLayout.  The TextView serves as the hint text.  I have a drawableStart attribute on the TextView.  When the user starts typing the TextView is hidden using code similar to that in the accepted answer from Dion.