# Is it possible to change the size of icon inside EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am creating a login window with username and password fields and in each I would like to put icons. When I add icon to EditText field I cannot change the size of icon.

Icon is inside EditText field because I want to change EditText background when it is focused.

I tried to put icon and EditText view inside LinearLayout, but I couldn't change layout background when EditText is focused.

> My EditText code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_name_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_border_selector"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#757575"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_grey_24dp"
    />
```

> EditText visual:

[image]

Comment: Check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250638/how-to-create-edittext-hint-as-text-with-image-in-android

Comment: @Rohit5k2 It will sound stupid of me, but I didn't think of that, thanks. One more question, I couldn't find method for adding padding or margin for the image? I tried to google it, a few hours and no useful info.

Comment: @JonasSeputis: Please check.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 your answer was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You can change the icon and use a smaller one on focus. This is the method you should use.

```
public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (
                                       int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

*Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text. Use 0 if you do not want a Drawable there. The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.*

> Now to add padding you can use this

```
 public void setCompoundDrawablePadding (int pad)
```

*Sets the size of the padding between the compound drawables and the text.*

Related XML Attributes:

```
android:drawablePadding
```

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablePadding%28int%29). There are many other methods you might find interesting.

Answer (score 19):

In case you'd like to solve the problem in xml, here's sample code where you can manipulate your image size/padding:

```
<!-- USERNAME INPUT -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_selector">

    <!-- INPUT -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_input"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/username_icon"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Username"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- ICON -->
    <ImageView
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/username_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/perm_group_personal_info"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A better way than setting by java would be by setting It inside a layered drawable as follows.

```
Layered list drawable is as under :

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item

        >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/bg_row_drop_completed"/>
            <size android:width="96dp"
                />
            <padding android:top="-15dp"
                android:bottom="-15dp"/>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/btn_add_bg_radius_purple" android:topRightRadius="@dimen/btn_add_bg_radius_purple"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        >
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/_ic_arrow_drop_up_normal" android:gravity="center_vertical"
            ></bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[see example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSiNG.png)