# how to set text and image as a hint in edittext in center?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i want to set image and text as hint in Edit text in center like this [image]

my  XML code is

```
<EditText  android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="40dp" 
android:id="@+id/ed_username" android:layout_marginBottom="152dp" 
android:hint="@string/username"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username_image" 
android:textColorHint="@color/skyblue" 
 android:background="@drawable/edittext_shape" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:ellipsize="start" android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"/>
```

please help me thanks in advance a

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250638/how-to-create-edittext-hint-as-text-with-image-in-android

Comment: @Shailesh Limbadiya look my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an image in edittext as drawableleft and remove it while getting focus.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Username"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourimage" />
```

remove it when getting focus

```
final EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean gotfocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(gotfocus){
    et.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
}
        else if(!gotfocus){
            if(et.getText().length()==0)
            et.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.yourimage, 0, 0, 0);
        }


    }
});
```

Comment: you say right but i want to set layout as i upload image but not getting how ? when i set like this the text will set center but image will set in left side now i want to set both are in center

Comment: you can adjust the padding by using drawablePadding attribute. If you want this in centre then set an empty text in centre and add the drawableLeft into that text and you need to manage that text in code also.

Comment: yes, thank for help i do like that and i got the solution

Answer (score 3):

You can do via Two Way

1.Create EditText like this.

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:hint="Search text"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_border"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp" 
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"     
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"/>
```

and in you layout create this file

**edit_text_bottom_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="-3dp"
            android:right="-3dp"
            android:top="-3dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#000" />

                <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />

            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

**2.** Make RelativeLayout like Below :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
            android:hint="hint"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text"
            android:background="#000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Generated Output is :

[image]

Comment: you said right but i want to use costume image to set the layout as i uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You can change the hint color as depicted below inside your java files.

> editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));

you can set drawlable to the edit text using following property

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"             
 android:drawableTop=""              
 android:drawableBottom=""    
 android:drawableStart=""     
 android:drawableEnd=""    
 android:drawableRight=""
```

but unfortunately you **can not** set drawlable at the **center** of the editText like this ,
**Alternatively** you can use background image which include your hint + image what ever you display and inside **editText.addTextChangedListener** you can remove that previously applied backgrund.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set your hint using `spannable`, and then you don't have to change your XML or layouts. This is an example with a textView. I never tried that with `setHint()`, but i think it will work the same way.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
SpannableStringBuilder span = new SpannableStringBuilder( "  Username" );
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
span.setSpan(new ImageSpan(icon), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 
tv.setText(span, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this it is very Simple

```
 et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //   loadData(et.getText().toString());
            // et.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(, 0, 0, 0);
            et.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            if (et.getText().length() == 0)
                et.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (et.getText().length() == 0)
                et.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    });
```

**and in Layout XML**

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EditText itself and make hint with image on any side of the EditText. Refer following for sample:

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString("  Mobile Number");
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.one);
    drawable.setBounds(50, 0, 0, 0);
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    spannable.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    editText.setHint(spannable);
```

**Note: you can adjust setBounds() over the image according to your preferred direction over the text.**