# How to add icon hint Edittext in center

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-imageview

How to add icon hint edittext in center

I have no idea to set that

and in xml file is not have android:drawbleCenter

How to create it

thanks for your help ;)

[image]

Comment: write your xml code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234036/how-to-set-text-and-image-as-a-hint-in-edittext-in-center

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11303236/8089770 try this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234036/how-to-set-text-and-image-as-a-hint-in-edittext-in-center

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can not set **drawable** at the center of the `EditText` like this, Alternatively, you can use background image which includes your **hint + image** what ever you display and inside,

Try below example.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
android:gravity="center">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Search" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can achieve this type of view using above XML code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` to EditText

Comment: Describe how that would help

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution

This is xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="#969696" />
</FrameLayout>
```

in onCreate()

```
edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            textIcon.setVisibility(s.length() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Try it!

Comment: how to resize `android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"`